# How to send the validation response to PHP controller instead of Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jQuery validator to test the phone field , but when i'm trying to send the form it's trying to execute ajax , I want it to run a function on the controller

```js
$("#form-profile-information").validate({
        rules: {            
            tel: {
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 10,
                number:true,
                phoneStartingWith6: true

            },
        },
            messages: {
                
            tel: "This is not a valid phone number",
        }
    });

if ($('#form-profile-information').valid()) {
    $('#form-profile-information').submit();
}
```

I'm also using this function in another form using ajax

```js
$.validator.setDefaults({submitHandler: function() {
        $('#signup-form .alert-danger').addClass('hidden');        
        params = $('#signup-form').serializeArray();
        ajax('post', params, function(data) {
            if(data) {
                $('#signup-form').slideUp();
                $('#email-signup').text(data.emailValue);
                return;
            }
        }, function(data){
            $('#signup-form .alert-danger p').text(data);
        });      
    }
});
```

When i use it I get Ajax.php executes and this error in the network : no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Check the URL of the ajax call or form submission. Does it have the same protocol and domain as the form page?

Comment: I think you only need the validate() function. That will block submission when the form is not valid. The function valid() immediately checks the validity of the form on loading the page like now in your code.

Comment: I'm calling ajax in another form , using the same validation test 
`$.validator.setDefaults({submitHandler: function() {
        $('#signup-form .alert-danger').addClass('hidden');        
        params = $('#signup-form').serializeArray();
        ajax('post', params, function(data) {
            if(data) {
                $('#signup-form').slideUp();
                $('#email-signup').text(data.emailValue);
                return;
            }
        }, function(data){
            $('#signup-form .alert-danger p').text(data);
        });      
    }
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ,

I had to add a condition on the ID before the validator

```
if($("#form-profile-information").length>0) {
    $.validator.setDefaults({submitHandler: function() {
       $('#signup-form .alert-danger').addClass('hidden');
       params = $('#signup-form').serializeArray();
       ajax('post', params, function(data) {
         if(data) {
           $('#signup-form').slideUp();
           $('#email-signup').text(data.emailValue);
           return;
         }
       }, 
       function(data){
         $('#signup-form .alert-danger p').text(data);
       });
    }
});
```